# External Login with Google Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using Asp.net core for develop web application with google Authentication Login

I succeed to manage up to get google credential and register the User at very first. But the problems is even user register to the Application with Google Credentials,it always ask for register again and again for the application.

I found that it happen due to ExternalLoginSignInAsync function calling and it always give false for that ,I changed these parameters and tried several times 
 isPersistent:false/true) and bypassTwoFactor : true/false I have test above all variations. But it always give false for result .As well as I tried with Google Authentication with Normally Registered User login.it also gave me same result

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl =null,string remoteError = null)
{
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (remoteError != null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: 
                {remoteError}";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new {ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information.";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            var result = await 
               _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, 
               info.ProviderKey, isPersistent:false, bypassTwoFactor : true);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("{Name} logged in with {LoginProvider} 
                provider.", info.Principal.Identity.Name, 
                info.LoginProvider);
                // return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                return LocalRedirect("/Customer/ProjectsApiKey/");
            }
```

Could you please any anyone who has already resolved this this problems help me to.I am expecting what should I do for check user already registered or not with Google Authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fault finally , it happened due to Email Confirmation thing,In my startup.cs class I have added the

```
 config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(config =>
    {
        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    })
        .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    // requires
    // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
    // using WebPWrecover.Services;
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

due to this it always required to confirm the user Login email even we use Google Authentication.In order to fix this what I have did was when I create new user using Google Authentication login I set user parameters including EmailConfirmation=true addition to User name & User Email.Then that bug was fixed. after that when I call below function

```
var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostConfirmationAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information during confirmation.";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };   comment dulith
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email ,EmailConfirmed=true};
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, SD.User);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        _logger.LogInformation("User created an account using {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
                       // return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                        return LocalRedirect("/Customer/ProjectsApiKey/");
                    }
                }
```

If user Exists

```
result.Succeeded is true
```

And also Thank you very much for previous answer.

Answer (score 3):

When GetExternalLoginInfoAsync returns false you can check user exists, if the user exists then add login.

Otherwise, the user does not have an account, then asks the user to create an account.

```
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
    }
    else
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var resultTemp = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
            if (resultTemp.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        // User does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
        var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        return View("ExternalLogin", new ExternalLoginViewModel { Email = email });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gökten Karadağ I'll try this one